# How to remove correspondence box from bmc template?

Tags: article

I'm very new at LaTeX and started using a bmc template to write an article/essay (https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/submission-guidelines/preparing-your-manuscript).
I already managed to remove the abstract box, but now I can't seem to remove the correspondence box below the author's name. I would like the main text to start below the author's name (now its more skewed to the right).
How do I fix this?
[image: pdf outcome]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to use the given template? Why not just use the `article` document class (say)?

Comment: No not really, but I like the esthetics of this template. The font and the blue bar for example. I have been searching on how to edit font etc myself, but I'm totally lost as I can't seem to install any packages into texmaker (miktex?).